# Can I pin a static value-type field long-term?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, static, value-type

I need to pin a static value-type field in memory, and I need the pin to be long-term, i.e. using a pinned `GCHandle` (or equivalent), **not** a pinned local variable (e.g. `fixed` blocks in C# or `pin_ptr` in C++/CLI)

I'm going crazy figuring this out, and I can't accept it isn't possible

So, I can pin a value type static field locally to a function, using `fixed`/`pin_ptr`, but I lose the pin when the function returns

With a `GCHandle` of type `GCHandleType.Pinned`, I can pin objects for as long as I like, but it only works on objects, reference types. I know value type static fields are internally stored as boxes (e: seems this only applies to non-primitive types, and I'm dealing with primitives), but I can't get a reference to the internal box object: if I pass the field to `GCHandle`, I create a new box from the current value of the field

From reading on .NET internals, I know that statics are stored inside assembly objects, which used to be non-GC and guaranteed to stay fixed in memory. But assemblies have been made collectible in recent versions of Core and Framework, and I don't know if this still applies (probably not, or we wouldn't need `FixedAddressValueTypeAttribute`)

I can't mark the field as `[FixedAddressValueType]`, because it's in a third-party assembly that I can't replace or modify

So, to sum up: I can pin anything, as long as I do it locally to a function. I can pin non-locally, but only if I have a reference to an object. Value type static fields *are* wrapped in an object, but I can't get a reference to it. Is there any hope of achieving this, ideally not relying on implementation-specific internals, or it's simply unsupported?

(... and to make it even harder, *ideally*, I need to do it from unmanaged code, using the native COM APIs. And, again ideally, I need to support both .NET Framework and .NET Core)

Comment: How do things need to access this pinned variable? just by its address?

Comment: Yes, just the address, but it positively needs to stay the same for the lifetime of the process